# Need once a day on first boot solution for running a program

Tags: windows-xp, backup, boot

I've been using Once-A-Day II from Karen's Tools to run a batch file upon booting each day. If for whatever reason, I reboot during the day a second time, OAD is smart enough not to run a second time. The only issue I have with the program is that it doesn't go away by itself after running (or not running). The batch file, itself, is a mass mover, renamer, backup thing that requires all the various files it moves NOT the be in use at the time it does it's thing. And since, I boot and then leave the computer to continue my morning perambulations, I don't mind the time it takes being added to my 'boot process.'

This would still be a usable solution, except I'm moving on to a new computer and this machine is going to a relative. One that would be confused by this program staying on screen and requiring an exit button click. And the backup procedure would still be germane to her use. (It's better, in fact. And will end more than the odd, "Backup, what backup?" dialogues I have had with her.

So, what I am specifically looking for is something that will run in the startup folder and will call a batch file, but only the first time on any given day it is run. It will not run thereafter until the calendar changes. AND, it will do things about as invisibly as possible.

This machine will be running WinXP, SP3. (and if the solution works in Win7x64bit, I would not complain in the least). And yes, I know that Karen's Tools do run in the environment I am going to, so I can keep my solution. But I wouldn't be adverse to changing, if something better and more on point exists.

Thanks in advance for your help, GM

Answer (score 1):

You could have the batch file check the for a dropped file containing or named the current date.  If it doesn't exist, drop it and run / if it exists, exit

Comment: just remember to clean up old dropped files

Comment: I think what you call dropped files, I call semaphores. I've used semaphores before, so it's a possible solution. And it's not like I don't have to do some editing (pruning) of the super batch file. But I was hoping for a utility to handle all of that. Still hoping, but fading ....